# Unable to import/deploy database to SQL Azure: "The service objective (Business/Web) specified is invalid."

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, ssms-2012

I'm trying to move my databases to a newer Azure subscription. I used to simply click "Deploy to Azure" on a local database from SSMS and have it deployed to a specified Azure server. Importing/Exporting a BACPAC file also works. However, I can't seem to do any of this on the new server. I keep getting the error:

> "The service objective 'Web' specified is invalid."

Googling around, I found this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/ssms-2014-deploy-database-feature-has-old-sql-azure-settings) explaining the need to update the CREATE DATABASE template to accommodate Azure Databases (Azure upgrade, I'm guessing). However, the [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999197) provided is specifically for SQL Server 2014 and I'm using SQL Server 2012. I checked other cumulative updates for 2012 [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2983249) but found no fix for the issue.

Is there any other way I can fix this without having to upgrade to 2014?

Just to summarize my software versions:

- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Management Studio 11.0.2100.60
- Local database: SQL Server 10.50.16000
- Old Azure server: SQL Server 11.0.9230
- New Azure server: SQL Server 13.0.15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because the latest V12 servers are not supporting the Web and Business Editions anymore. If you don't want to upgrade to SSMS 2014, you can create a V11 server and import your DB on this server. However this is only a temporary solution as Web and Business edition databases will be retired in September. At this point you will have to work with the latest tools to avoid this problem.

Comment: I did end up creating a V11 server instead due to project restrictions. Thanks for explaning this. Will definitely take note of it.

Comment: how do you go about creating a v11 server, as I cannot seem to get this right, and cannot find online help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hotfix for it you can download and install on your machine. Please navigate to: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2936603
You need to enter your email then download link will be sent to your email address. Then install it on your machine and you can see the following options:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but the hotfix you're providing is for 2014 too, same with what I included in my post. Besides, the question was looking for a fix that doesn't involve upgrading to 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Install the database as a Data Project into Visual Studio, 
Set the target framework in the properties window to SQL Azure, 
Build the project and resolve any unsupported issues.
Publish to your azure site.

I have tried the above and did not work for me - this solution worked!